# Bootstrap tabs with specific buttons for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My page is generated from PHP and the TABS and TAB PANES are populated from MySQL, in each PANE there are 2 buttons and 2 hidden inputs that dictate which TAB should be navigated based on the button clicked and the previous hidden input.

Now the button `SIM` on `TAB HEADER #1` does open the correct TAB but it's the only button working.

```js
$("#btn-next").click(function(event) {
  var valorProximo = $(this).prev().attr('id');
  $('.tab' + valorProximo).tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <li class="active"><a class="tabValidacao" href="#aValidacao" data-toggle="tab">First Active</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab1" href="#a1" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab2" href="#a2" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab3" href="#a3" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab4" href="#a4" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab5" href="#a5" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab6" href="#a6" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #6</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab7" href="#a7" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #7</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="tab8" href="#a8" data-toggle="tab">Tab Header #8</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="aValidacao">
    <h3>Bla bla First Active:</h3>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a1">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 1:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="3" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">SIM</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">NAO</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a2">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 2:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="4" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">PING OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="6" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">PING NOK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a3">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 3:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">ENCAMINHAR</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">ENCAMINHAR</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a4">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 4:</h3>

    <p>Text text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="4" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">TESTE OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">TESTE NOK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a5">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 5:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">TESTE OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">TESTE NOK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a6">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 6:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="6" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">NOK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a7">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 7:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="7" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">NOK</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="a8">
    <br />
    <h3>Tab 8:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <h3>Action:</h3>

    <p>Text Text</p>
    <input class="hidden" id="1" />
    <button class="btn btn-success btnNavi" id="btn-next">OK</button>
    <input class="hidden" id="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-danger">NOK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/503/)!

Comment: ID MUST BE UNIQUE ! (sorry for uppercase but very important), rewrite your code. [sorry again]

Comment: @YenneInfo will try it. Thank you.

Comment: Take this : http://www.bootply.com/9k6Q5pPES1

Comment: @YenneInfo Thank you. It was the ID.

Thank you for the bootply also. I think i will stick with it. It's efficient. 

Merci beaucoup!

Comment: nada ^^ you're welcome

Comment: @YenneInfo care to answer so we can close the tread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem is in following HTML5 rules (or older) the ID have to be unique.*

**Extract :**

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). [DOM]
>
> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

You can find more doc [here at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Here is a way where this code can run : [link bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9k6Q5pPES1)